# Thinkpad T14 Gen 3 Intel on Ubuntu - sleep mode issue

Tags: suspend, thinkpad

I recently purchased a thinkpad T14 gen 3. Installed Ubuntu only on it, worked like a charm until I closed the lid.
Whenever the computer is on sleep mode, I cannot use it afterward. I have to reboot it manually.
I tried to change BIOS setting from Sleep mode "Windows and Linux" to "Linux S3". It didn't solve the issue. Only now I have a frozen mouse that appears and screen turn black on a 10 sec period of time.

Any idea of what I should do ? I might consider sending back the computer...

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How did you update your BIOS? Via fwupdmgr ?

Comment: Had some trouble updating is from ubuntu so i just gave up and install a windows 10 version just for using Lenovo tool, then i came back to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

> I solved it by updating the BIOS !

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1432761/2).</sup>